# Синтаксическая ошибка php

Tags: php

Здравствуйте. Подскажите пожалуйста, почему выдается ошибка

syntax error, unexpected '['

```
static $points = [
    '1' => ['3' => 8.4, '2' => 7.1, '4' => 5.3],
    '2' => ['5' => 9.1],
    '3' => ['6' => 8.2, '5' => 4.2],
    '4' => ['6' => 7.3],
    '5' => ['6' => 6.3],
];
```

Язык на котором написано php

Comment: У меня не возникает такой ошибки. Возможно следует убрать запятую в строке:
`> '5' => ['6' => 6.3],`

Comment: У вас версия php ниже php 5.4. В которой можно объявлять массив таким образом. Переходите на версию выше, либо используйте `array()`

Answer (score 3):

Как уже подчеркнул `Алексей Шиманский`, у вас проблема с версией `PHP`, она ниже версии 5.4.

В версиях `>= 5.4` добавили возможность объявлять массив с помощью `[]`.

Вам, чтобы решить проблему, нужно заменить все `[...]` на `array(...)`.

В итоге ваш код будет выглядеть так:

```
static $points = array(
    '1' => array('3' => 8.4, '2' => 7.1, '4' => 5.3),
    '2' => array('5' => 9.1),
    '3' => array('6' => 8.2, '5' => 4.2),
    '4' => array('6' => 7.3),
    '5' => array('6' => 6.3),
);
```

[Ссылка на документацию](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.types.array.php)